# Google bookmark box on Google Sites

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

Is there a way to get (shown under following link) the "Add Bookmark" box (or equivalent link) on Google Site pages / side bar?

https://www.google.com/bookmarks/

Edited (To make it more clear:)

I would like a box/link on my google site, that user (logged in with gmail account) can click and current page URL is automatically popped up for bookmark in their "Google Bookmark Service" (not on browser).

Comment: Why did you tag this with [google-apps-script] ?

Comment: Wouldn't this be something thats directly not possible, and some scripting is required? "Add Bookmark" contains from js code..

Answer (score 0):

GAS is a cloud scripting language, meaning it runs on a server, not on your computer. Its interaction with your Browser is very limited, I don't think adding a bookmark is something that can be done in this context. You could also ask / search on [Google sites forum](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/sites)

Comment: Yes, understood. I didn't make my question very clear :(

I have google site with restricted access. Only those logged in with google account can access the page.

Now what I intended was, to have a link on my website, so that when  logged in google user press the link, it should automatically take them to "Google Bookmarks (their could service)", with current page's URL populated.  (Not intending to add bookmark on browser)

Comment: ok, that's clear now ;-) sorry for my misunderstanding.  That said, scripts running on a site run under the identity of the owner (you I guess) so even logged users cannot be identified by the script. so I don't think it could bring a solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this old discusion maybe it throws a light on your doubt

http://productforums.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/sites/1Y14SOmc3qY

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no Google Bookmarks API. Google offers an API for most obscure services and I'm not sure why Bookmarks was left out. If they did, you'd have a chance using Google Apps Script.

Out side of Apps Scripts, you may try [this gadget](http://www.google.com/ig/directory?type=gadgets&url=www.google.com/ig/modules/bookmarks.xml) and insert it in your site. It may require some tweaking (you can view the source) but help on tweaking that is out of the scope of Apps Script and Sites.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using a sharing URL.  Like this URL:

```
https://www.google.com/bookmarks/mark?op=edit&bkmk={url}&title={title}&annotation={text}&labels={hash_tags}
```

You can set any of these to whatever you want, or just not include them in the URL:

- `bkmk` : Holds your URL.
- `title` : Holds your title.
- `annotation` : Holds your text.
- `labels`: Holds your keywords or hashtags.

I maintain a social sharing URLs GitHub project, check us out! [GitHub: Social Share URLs](https://github.com/bradvin/social-share-urls).

[image: Social Share URLs]